# C++ virtual inheritance no member named in base class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve an inheritance problem, where a derived class Snake inherits from LivingThing -> Animal -> Reptile, however, when I don't add `virtual void crawl()` to class LivingThing, the compiler says `error: no member named 'crawl' in 'LivingThing'`. Now I don't want to have to implement a virtual void in LivingThing which is specific for Snakes.

```
#include <iostream>

class LivingThing
{
  public:
    void breathe()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm breathing as a living thing." << std::endl;
    }

   virtual void crawl() {} //dont' want this
};

class Animal : virtual public LivingThing
{
  public:
    void breathe()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm breathing as an animal." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Reptile : virtual public LivingThing
{
  public:
    void crawl()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm crawling as a reptile." << std::endl;
    }

    void breathe()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm breathing as a reptile." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Snake : public Animal, public Reptile
{
  public:
    void breathe()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm breathing as a snake." << std::endl;
    }

    void crawl()
    {
        std::cout << "I'm crawling as a snake." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    LivingThing *snake = new Snake();

    snake->breathe();
    snake->crawl();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call the function `move`.  Then the derived class can decide how it wants to move.

Comment: When you upcast object to it's base type, you can only use methods which are declared in this base class.

Comment: Change the variable to `Snake *snake`.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok, I admit calling it move would be possible in this case, however if I want to have more specific methods which are only implemented at the lowest derived level this won't work, what if I need a very_specific_snake_method() ?

Comment: "what if I need a very_specific_snake_method() ?" then you can only call it on `Snake *`

Comment: The point of polymorphism is to share a common interface among related classes.  If you have a specific function that you don't want part of that interface then you'll either have to cast to see if it is a snake before you call it (normally this is a design mistake) or make a common function that will then dispatch to the specific function.  Normally with polymorphism you don't know what the pointer actually points to so you need that generic interface.

Comment: Btw your problem is completely unrelated to virtual inheritance.

Comment: I agree that a Reptile is a kind of LivingThing. But I think you made a mistake in that it should have been a kind of Animal. I also think that a Snake should not have been made a kind of Animal __and__ a kind of Reptile, because, again, a Reptile should be a kind of Animal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`snake->crawl();` tries to access `crawl` through a `LivingThing*`, without a v-table reference, `LivingThing*` cannot call `Snake::crawl`.

In your current example you could just change the `LivingThing` pointer to be a `Snake` pointer.

In a more complex situation:

If you know that the pointer you're calling `crawl` on points to an object that is  infact a `Snake` then you can `static_cast` the pointer.

```
if(Snake* snake = static_cast<Snake*>(livingThing)) 
    snake->crawl();
```

If you have no guarantee that the living thing is actually a `Snake` and you have [`rtti`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) available then you can use `dynamic_cast`.

```
if(Snake* snake = dynamic_cast<Snake*>(livingThing)) 
    snake->crawl();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you upcast object to it's base type, you can only use methods which are declared in this base class. So if you don't want to declare `crawl` method in your base type, you've to downcast your object before using this method:

```
LivingThing *creature = new Snake();
creature->breathe();
if(Snake* snake = dynamic_cast<Snake*>(creature)) snake->crawl();
```

Comment: `static_cast<Snake*>(snake)->crawl();` ew.  In this case you know it is correct but in the general case you won't know what the pointer actually points to and you should use `dynamic_cast` to make sure it is a proper cast.